# How to change header/page title of change list page in Django Admin

Tags: python, django

I'm working on Django.And I wanted to change the header in the change list page in the Django admin as marked with red color in the pic

[image]

and my admin.py file looks like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin


from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):

    change_form_template = 'change_form.html'

    add_form_template='add_form.html'

    list_display = ('first_name','last_name','email','is_staff', 'is_active',)
    list_filter = ('first_name','email', 'is_staff', 'is_active',)

    search_fields = ('email','first_name','last_name','a1','a2','city','state','pincode')
    ordering = ('first_name',)

    add_fieldsets = (
        ('Personal Information', {
            # To create a section with name 'Personal Information' with mentioned fields
            'description': "",
            'classes': ('wide',),  # To make char fields and text fields of a specific size
            'fields': (('first_name','last_name'),'email','a1','a2','city','state','pincode','check',
                       'password1', 'password2',)}
        ),
        ('Permissions',{
            'description': "",
            'classes': ('wide', 'collapse'),
            'fields':( 'is_staff', 'is_active','date_joined')}),
    )
```

So my question is how to change the header in the change list page as shown in the pic??

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To makes changes like that first you have to add a line in the admin file :

```
change_list_template='change_list_form.html'
```

So your admin file will look like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin


from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):

    change_list_template='change_list_form.html'

    change_form_template = 'change_form.html'

    add_form_template='add_form.html'

    list_display = ('first_name','last_name','email','is_staff', 'is_active',)
    list_filter = ('first_name','email', 'is_staff', 'is_active',)

    search_fields = ('email','first_name','last_name','a1','a2','city','state','pincode')
    ordering = ('first_name',)

    add_fieldsets = (
        ('Personal Information', {
            # To create a section with name 'Personal Information' with mentioned fields
            'description': "",
            'classes': ('wide',),  # To make char fields and text fields of a specific size
            'fields': (('first_name','last_name'),'email','a1','a2','city','state','pincode','check',
                       'password1', 'password2',)}
        ),
        ('Permissions',{
            'description': "",
            'classes': ('wide', 'collapse'),
            'fields':( 'is_staff', 'is_active','date_joined')}),
    )
```

After that go to the templates folder and add a html file with name : `change_list_form.html`

Then in the file `change_list_form.html` add following code:

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_urls static admin_list %}


{% block content_title %}<h1>Type here your new header</h1>{% endblock %}
```

That's all you have to do.